# How to call function that uses hooks in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to add typescript(im of course new to that) to my react project. I wrote a hook that fetches data from api that i wrote. I want to add typings but typescript won't compile I think because of undefined state at the beginning of rendering. I'm guessing. The problem is with calling a formatData function inside VictoryPie component.The rror that i get:

```
TypeScript error: Argument of type 'boolean | never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data[]'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Data[]'.  TS2345

    26 |         <VictoryPie
    27 |           colorScale={['tomato', 'orange', 'gold', 'cyan', 'navy']}
  > 28 |           data={formatData(graphData)}
       |                            ^
    29 |           x="description"
    30 |           y="amount"
    31 |         />
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {useFetch} from '../hooks';
import {VictoryPie} from 'victory';

interface Data {
  _id: number,
  id: string,
  userName: string,
  amount: number,
  description: string,
  time: string,
}

const Graph = () => {
  const [graphData, loading] = useFetch('/api/Kamil');
  const formatData = (inputData: Array<Data>) => {
    return inputData.map(
      ({_id, id, time, userName, ...keepAttrs}) => keepAttrs,
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        'Loading...'
      ) : (
        <VictoryPie
          colorScale={['tomato', 'orange', 'gold', 'cyan', 'navy']}
          data={formatData(graphData)}
          x="description"
          y="amount"
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default Graph;
```

Hook

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function useFetch(url: string) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await axios(url);
    console.log(response);
    setData(response.data)
    setLoading(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);
  return [data, loading];
}
export { useFetch };
```

Comment: I think you should return an object rather than an array in your custom cook, it would be `return {data, loading};`, the type of loading will be `boolean` and the type of data will be `Data[]`

Comment: i changed and now i got 

TypeScript error: Type '{ data: never[]; loading: boolean; }' is not an array type.  TS2461

Comment: change `useState([])` by `useState([] as Data[])`

Comment: same error: TypeScript error: Type '{ data: any[]; loading: boolean; }' is not an array type.  TS2461
Tried with [data, loading] as well with {data, loading}

Comment: of course in your component you should replace `const [graphData, loading] = useFetch('/api/Kamil');` by `const {data: graphData, loading} = useFetch('/api/Kamil');`

Comment: Now i got TypeScript error: Property 'graphData' does not exist on type '{ data: any[]; loading: boolean; }'.  TS2339
Whats the problem here? graphData is not defined before fetching, right? Btw without typescript this hook worked

Comment: Did you write `const {data: graphData, loading} = useFetch...` ? I supose you write `const {graphData, loading} = useFetch...`

Comment: yes, I did change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here.

You need to declare that your hook returns tuple. Now typescript assumes you're returning array of data and loading in any order.

Also you need to declare what kind of result do you expect as fetch result.

Your hook should look something like

```
function useFetch<ExpectedResult>(url: string, initialData: ExpectedResult): [ExpectedResult, boolean] {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await axios(url);
    console.log(response);
    setData(response.data)
    setLoading(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, [url]); // <<-- when url is changed you propably want to re-fetch
  return [data, loading];
}
```

and then when you use it

do it like

```
type DataFromServer = Date[];

const [data, isLoading] = useFetch<DataFromServer>('/api/Kamil', []);
```

Now typescript knows what `[data, isLoading]` are supposed to be.

Comment: That is correct. To make it work i had to change ```javascript
type DataFromServer = Data[]; // before it was Date[]
```
Need more readings on that, docs is not enough. Thank you